# Get-content Pipe to Select String and retrieve ComputerName

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to write a script that I can look at a list of remote servers, search for certain file type. Then if the File consists with a certain string i want to know what file that is and on what computer.

I started with the basics but when I do Select-String I can't retrieve the file nor can i find the computer name, it just outputs the same string as i have in my script.

I'm sure i'm missing something basic but any suggestions here will greatly be appreciated.

```
$servers = ArrayofServers

    ForEach ($server in $Servers){ 
                invoke-command -computername $server {Get-ChildItem "D:\Folder\Location\Windows\" -Include *.txt -Recurse |

                Get-Content | 

                Select-String 'String to Select' | 

                Out-String 

    } -Credential $credential }
```

I want to be able to Select FileName,Pscomputername and Select-String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it easier to break the pipeline. I have tested this code successfully:

```
$Servers = @("ArrayofServers")
foreach ($Server in $Servers)
{ 
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock {
        $Results = $false
        $SearchResults = Get-ChildItem "D:\Folder\Location\Windows\" -Include *.txt -Recurse 
        foreach ($SearchResult in $SearchResults)
        {
            If ($SearchResult | Get-Content | Select-String 'String to Select')
            {
                $SearchResult.FullName
                $SearchResult | Get-Content
                $Results = $true
            }
        }
        If ($Results)
        {
            $env:COMPUTERNAME
        }
    } -Credential $Credential 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate that. I am fairly new to power shell and learn just by trying to do things i need to get done. I started doing something similar last night but got stuck with the Filename it kept coming back at inputstream.